# Does record get committed to Kafka when there is out of sync replica and ACK=-1?

Tags: apache-kafka

running confluent-kafka 3.3.1e Kafka 0.11.0x

- I have a single partition with replicas = 3.
- My producer is running with ack=-1
- The partition has 1 out of sync replica
- Replica lag time max ms = 10000
- Min insync replicas = 2

1) Will the record get committed from the producer when ack=-1

2) How can I get the out of sync replica back in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) With `acks=-1` Kafka will accept records as long as there are `min.insync.replicas` in-sync replicas.

So assuming `min.insync.replicas` is 1 or 2 for your topic, with a single replica out of sync, yes the record will be accepted by Kafka

2) In a normal case, Kafka always tries to keep all replicas in-sync. If that's not happening then you want to check the broker that is hosting the out-of-sync replica as something is wrong. Is this broker running? Is it healthy? Is it overloaded? Are other partitions on this broker also out-of-sync?

Older versions of Kafka also had some replication issues which could cause out of sync replicas. A good workaround these is to force a controller re-election:

```
zookeeper-shell [ZK_HOST:ZK_POST] rmr /controller
```

Comment: I have min in sync replicas = 2 and the topic is = 3 replicas. So in this case I would be goo then. As for the broker how do you put back in sync? I rebooted it and it seems to have done the trick. Is that ok? And running Kafka 0.11.0.x

Comment: With 0.11, the method I recommended (electing a new controller) often does the trick and has less impact on the cluster. If that does not work then yes rebooting the bad broker is usually the fix.

Comment: Thanks. I approved the answer.